# Does the `do` keyword run a block or treat it as an expression?

Tags: expression, raku, do-notation, rakudo

The [docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/control#index-entry-control_flow_do-do) state that "The simplest way to run a block where it cannot be a stand-alone statement is by writing `do` before it" and provide the following example:

```
# This dies half of the time 
do { say "Heads I win, tails I die."; Bool.pick } or die; say "I win.";
```

However, `do` doesn't seem to cause all blocks to run.  In particular, it doesn't seem to run blocks with a signature:

```
do -> $a = 42 { say "ran with $a"; 0 } or die; say 'done'; # OUTPUT: «done»
```

So would it be better to say that `do` treats a block as an expression which **sometimes** causes it to be run?  Or is Rakudo incorrect in its behavior here?  Or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: do -> $a { say "ran with $a"; 0 }(42) or die; say 'done';

Comment: @Holli I understand how to invoke a block :-)  But my point is that the `do` in that line doesn't seem to do anything – that produces the same output if you omit the `do`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Afaik:

- Like all "statement prefixes", `do` consumes a "blorst" (block or statement) on its right and treats it as a statement.
- `do`'s only special power is that it evaluates to the value of the (last) statement. I think this is the only sense in which there's any sense of "expression" in its operation.

This interacts with the following behaviors, which are unrelated to `do`:

- When a "bare" block (`{...}`) is treated as a statement, it runs the block.
- Other blocks, treated as a statement, don't (or [shouldn't](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1381)), run.

I think the fix to the doc sentence is something like:

> The simplest way to run a **bare** block where it <strike>cannot be</strike> **is not behaving as** a stand-alone statement is by writing `do` before it"

Though I don't know where/if the doc talks about the difference between bare blocks and other blocks.

Comment: Interesting. `say 0; do -> $a = 1 { say $a }; say 2` seems like it "ought" to print 0, 1, 2 – that is, saying to `do` a non-bare block feels like the same thing as calling the block with no arguments (just as `do` before a bare block is the same as calling that block with no arguments…)

Comment: Ponder what's in the issue I linked. Perhaps non-bare blocks recognized by the blorst rule will trigger a warning, or become a compile-time error, once RakuAST lands?

Comment: That is an inexact fix. It **is** behaving as a statement. It is also returning its final value, which is something that statements don't generally do. Also every block that is treated as a statement get run immediately. It is the blocks which are treated as expressions which do not run. (`$f = { $_ × 2 }`)

Comment: @BradGilbert Thanks! .@codesections I'd like to delete my answer, because I'm confident Brad is right and my answer is badly misleading. Please unaccept my answer (and, I suggest, accept Brad's answer, which seems to me very clean and elegant, and which I know is grounded in a decade plus of growing mastery of both Raku and Rakudo's source, instead). TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The `do` keyword turns a statement into an expression.

```raku
my @b = do for @a { $_² if $_ %% 2 }

my $c = do if @b > 4 { +@b } else { 3 }
```

A bare block can either be a statement:

```raku
my $a = 1;
say $a;
{
  my $a = 2;
  say $a;
}
say $a;
```

or it can be an expression:

```raku
my $code = { … }
```

When you use `do` with a bare block it acts as the statement form, but also returning the last value evaluated.

```raku
my $result = do { say 'hi'; 5 }
# hi

say $result;
# 5
```

---

A pointy block on the other hand is always an expression.

```raku
my $code = -> $ { … }
```

Even if you don't assign it anywhere

```raku
say 'a';
-> { say 'hi' }
do -> { say 'bye' }
say 'b';

# a
# b
```

It is pointless to use `do` with something that is already an expression.

---

Note that the `do` keyword in the compiler takes a `blorst` (block or statement) instead of just a statement because it doesn't make much sense to turn the block into a statement just to undo that and turn it into an expression-like block so that it will return its last value.

Basically `blorst` only ever captures a statement, but it captures the block type of statement directly to simplify the internals of the compiler.